# Large web application split into several smaller web apps leads to pathing problems

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I'm in the process of splitting a very large web application project into several, more manageable projects.The problem I'm having is with pathing.

Since the new projects used to share a common root (`www.mysite.com`), they would sometimes refer to each other using a relative path, such as `/otherApp/somepage.jsp`.

Now since the applications have their own root, if an application tries to refer to the same relative path, the following is produced:

`www.mysite.com/currentApp/otherApp/somePage.jsp`

Is there any way to define an app's root as `www.mysite.com` while keeping the path to the web app as `www.mysite.com/currentApp`?

I am currently using **Tomcat 7** and developing in **Eclipse Java EE Luna**

Comment: What web framework are you using?  You may have to stop using relative paths or do some url rewriting.  Maybe both!

Comment: Hi Robert, I am not currently using any kind of framework, only Tomcat. I have the web.xml, as well as, the tomcat configuration at my disposal.

Comment: The short answer is you'll either have to stop using relative paths or use apache or something like that as a reverse proxy to your multiple tomcat apps.

Comment: Replacing relative paths would take a large amount of time. I'll look into setting up a reverse proxy. Thanks for the help Robert.